# Does "explicit" keyword have any effect on a default constructor?

Tags: c++, default-constructor, explicit

Is there a reason to use the `explicit` keyword for a constructor that doesn't take any arguments? Does it have any effect? I'm wondering because I just came across the line

```
explicit char_separator()
```

near the end of the page documenting [`boost::char_separator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/tokenizer/char_separator.htm), but it's not explained any further there.

Comment: Not a dupe; this question is about a very specific corner case of the `explicit` keyword.

Comment: That's not a function, that's a constructor - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean/121163#121163

Comment: @larsmans Hard to tell without seeing some real example

Comment: @VJo: check `<boost/token_functions.hpp>`, it's there.

Comment: @larsman If we are taking about `char_separator`, described in the link above (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/tokenizer/char_separator.htm), then it is a constructor, and this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, it does have an effect.**

Compare:

```
struct A
{
    A() {}
};

void foo(A) {}

int main()
{
    foo({}); // ok
}
```

and:

```
struct A
{
    explicit A() {}
};

void foo(A) {}

int main()
{
    foo({}); // error
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer starting with C++11. When asking the question back then, I was still using C++03, where brace initialization was not available. Boost was already one step ahead :)

Answer (score 16):

Reading [explanation of members](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/tokenizer/char_separator.htm#members) :

```
explicit char_separator(const Char* dropped_delims,
                        const Char* kept_delims = "",
                        empty_token_policy empty_tokens = drop_empty_tokens)
explicit char_separator()
```

The `explicit` keyword for the 1st constructor requires explicit creation of objects of char_separator type.
[What does the explicit keyword mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean) covers the explicit keyword very well.

The `explicit` keyword for the 2nd constructor is a noise and is ignored.

**EDIT**

From the c++ standard :

7.1.2 p6 tells :

> The explicit specifier shall be used only in declarations of
>   constructors within a class declaration; see 12.3.1.

12.3.1 p2 tells :

> An explicit constructor constructs objects just like non-explicit
>   constructors, but does so only where direct-initialization syntax
>   (8.5) or where casts (5.2.9, 5.4) are explicitly used. A default
>   constructor may be an explicit constructor; such a constructor will be
>   used to perform default-initialization or value-initialization (8.5).
>   [Example:

```
class Z {
public:
explicit Z();
explicit Z(int);
// ...
};
Z a;               // OK: default-initialization performed
Z a1 = 1;          // error: no implicit conversion
Z a3 = Z(1);       // OK: direct initialization syntax used
Z a2(1);           // OK: direct initialization syntax used
Z* p = new Z(1);   // OK: direct initialization syntax used
Z a4 = (Z)1;       // OK: explicit cast used
Z a5 = static_cast<Z>(1); // OK: explicit cast used
```

> —end example]

So, the default constructor with the `explicit` keyword is the same as without this keyword.

Comment: "The explicit keyword for the 2nd constructor is a noise and is ignored." what?

Comment: This answer is wrong, at least when considering brace initialization in modern versions of C++. Proof: https://godbolt.org/z/zdNvTp (if the `explicit` keyword is removed, the code compiles).

Comment: `explicit` affects whether certain initializations can be performed.